# Can't show looped JSON data on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

After I pulled data from a mock API using fetch, I managed to loop the data and have it posted on my console. I'm having trouble posting the data on a div to be shown on the page.
Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const fetchData = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('https://n161.tech/api/dummyapi/user?limit=5&page=1');
    const data = await response.json();
    //  items = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      var obj = data.data[i];
      console.log(obj);
    }
  }
  fetchData();
});
```

html for reference(not designed with CSS yet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pictures&users</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- <script scr="fetch.js"></script> -->
    <script src="fetch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col div1">Column</div>
                  <div class="col">Column</div>
                </div>
              </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I want one of the DIVs to post certain values from the fetched JSON. The other would be used for a hardcoded image. I
I'll of course add the

and  I need for the specific values. I'm having trouble achieving this in vanilla JS.

the JSON used for reference

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "nameTitle": "ms",
      "firstName": "Madeleine",
      "lastName": "Brown",
      "image": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/65.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "nameTitle": "mr",
      "firstName": "Akseli",
      "lastName": "Ruona",
      "image": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/90.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "nameTitle": "ms",
      "firstName": "Jennifer",
      "lastName": "West",
      "image": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/53.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "nameTitle": "mrs",
      "firstName": "Carlucia",
      "lastName": "Das neves",
      "image": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/52.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "nameTitle": "mrs",
      "firstName": "Silviane",
      "lastName": "Peixoto",
      "image": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/76.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "total": 5,
  "page": 1,
  "limit": 5
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? `div.innerHTML += obj.someproperty`

Comment: What does _posting the data on a div_  mean?

Comment: @Cue It means "displaying the data in a DIV"

Comment: Basically, replace `console.log(obj)` with code that formats the data the way you want in HTML, and append that to the DIV.

Comment: @Barmar Something seems to be missing. Like I need the specific keys and values so I can post them within my custom div. The page has two different divs in a CSS grid. I want to post the specific values in specific places.

Comment: `div1.innerHTML += obj.property1; div2.innerHTML += obj.property2;`

Comment: Of course, that's a simplification, but it's the basic structure. Format the properties, and append them to the appropriate DIVs.

Comment: Can you add the html code? And possibly any code you tried?

Comment: ```<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col div1">Column</div>
                  <div class="col">Column</div>
                </div>
              </div>
</body>```

Comment: Many details are missing for us to understand what you want to do. How do you want the data to be displayed? Why 2 different output divs? How do we decide which data goes to which div? Too bad because it seemed like a very simple problem and we sure could have helped. Why not clearly write in the question what is the exact expected output?

Comment: @Vincent I've added the HTML to the question, note that its not designed yet. Basically I want the JSON array to be displayed on one of the divs, once the grid is complete, I want all the users I've fetched from the mock API to be posted in the front. For example using the user name, id and avatar posted in my custom DIV.

Comment: "I want one of the DIVs to post certain values from the fetched JSON" => Which div ? And what is "certain values"? Please say exactly what you need.

Comment: div with the class of div 1.
I want the user id, user name, and avatar to be displayed on the div. in the array the respective keys are 'id', 'firstName', 'image'

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to build the html as string then append it to html so you need to add `id` to your main div

```
 <body>
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="row" class="row">
          <div id="test" class="col div1">Column</div>
          <div class="col">Column</div>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

then update your js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const fetchData = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('https://n161.tech/api/dummyapi/user?limit=5&page=1');
    const data = await response.json();
    //  items = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
    div = document.getElementById('row');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        var str ='<div>'+data.data[i].nameTitle +' '+data.data[i].firstName +' '+ data.data[i].lastName+ '</div>';
        str +='<img src="'+data.data[i].image+'" alt="'+data.data[i].firstName + data.data[i].lastName+'">';
        div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
    }
  }
  fetchData();
```

You can easily modify the output as you want and also use bootstrap class 
[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you! it works, however it shows only one of the items in the array, it should show all of them.

Comment: Are you sure? it's work for me check answer I update it.